# how do i zoom several images on hover without changing its width and height?

Tags: html, css, image, animation, zooming

im creating gallery with several images and on hover i want it to zoom the image without scaling the box. im using bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12"><img class="galleryimg" src="images/3GALLERY-1A.jpg" width="100%" height="" alt=""/></div>
 <div class="col-12 "><img class="galleryimg" src="images/3GALLERY-2A.jpg" width="100%" height="" alt=""/></div></row>
```

css-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
img.galleryimg{
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;}

img.galleryimg:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

Comment: nope. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE58HuipqjI something like this but this tutorial is using bgimg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Zoom an Image on Mouse Hover using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491728/how-to-zoom-an-image-on-mouse-hover-using-css)

Answer (score 5):

Try changing this line:

```js
transition: 0.4s ease;
```

to

```js
transition: transform 0.4s ease;
```

That should fix it.

EDIT: For the zoom effect shown, try like this:

```css
.col-12 {
  /* Change example sizes */
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img.galleryimg{
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;}

img.galleryimg:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    width: 100%;}
```

```html
<!-- Example image used -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ecad24d406a8b8fd5753363a4f691d9a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="100" height="100" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="col-12 "><img class="galleryimg" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ecad24d406a8b8fd5753363a4f691d9a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="100" height="100" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. its still not what i want. its more like this youtube.com/watch?v=cE58HuipqjI  but mine is currently just the img scaling